# Exporting IP Addresses using Python Script

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a script that will extract IP addresses (from a text document) that have appeared over 30 times (the same address). Once found I'm trying to export those IP addresses into a separate text document.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import re

appears = 0

myLog = open('auth.log', 'r')

for line in myLog:
    if re.match(("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"), line):
        attempts +=1

print 'The number of times this IP Address appears is', appears
```

When I run the script I'm not finding any IP addresses in the log file, there's hundreds in there but nothing is being found. Is there a problem with the regular expression or a combination of different things.

Is there any chance I can create a Regular Expression to search for the following:

```
> Failed password for bin from 211.167.103.172
```

Sorry if this is a bit vague, new to Python and still getting used to things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first one is the caret (`^`) in the beginning of the regex. What that means is "search for this pattern, starting at the beginning of the string". If your log file looks like `Failed password for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, the text at the beginning is going to invalidate the regex. The other issue is the `.match` function. This will start the search at the beginning of the string, as though you had a caret in front. Replace this with `.search` and you should be good:

```
if re.search(("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"), line):
```

---

Another thing: the `appears` variable is set outside of the `for` loop, so every time you iterate over a line it's going to reset the variable. I would declare a dictionary of counts for each IP, and increment the values as you loop through:

```
import re

ip_counts = {}

myLog = open('auth.log', 'r')

for line in myLog:
    match = re.search(("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"), line)
    if match:
        ip = match.group()
        if ip not in ip_counts:
            ip_counts[ip] = 1
        else:
            ip_counts[ip] += 1

for ip in ip_counts:
    count = ip_counts[ip]
    if count > 30:
        print('IP {} had {} attempts.'.format(ip, count))
```

Comment: Another issue is the indentation

Comment: Try printing something under the `if match` clause. If you're not seeing any output there's a problem with the regex.

Comment: Could you make a gist with a few lines of the log? Scrub out any IPs with zeroes if you need to. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Also try adding a print statement under the main `for` loop to make sure the file is being read properly.

Answer (score 0):

Jura is on the right track. You can also upgrade the regex to the following:

```
(Failed).*?(password).*?\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

It will include only the lines you are looking for and not all lines with an ip-address in it.

But I'm far from a regex expert, it might be not perfect.

You can go [here](http://www.regexr.com/) to fiddle with your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified expression version:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

e = re.compile(r'((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})')

with open('log.txt') as f:
    ips = Counter([e.search(line).group() for line in f if e.search(line)])

thirty_plus = [ip for ip,count in ips.most_common() if count > 30]

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join(thirty_plus))
```